# Null Pointer Error in object oriented program

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am working on a program that takes input from a user into an array that is kept in a seperate class and then takes data from a file and inputs into into the same array.
The issue im havaing is that the code compiles but i recieve a null pointer error in the main at the call for addStock as well as the first while statement in addStock.
Thank You for your help.

INVENTORY.JAVA

```
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    //program skeleton is based on previous inventory.java(v 1.0) which was in turn based on        divider.java(v 1.0)
    //item data is now moved into a stock array using the stock.class,see stock.java notes   for info on its implementation.
    public class Inventory
    {
    private static int MAX_ITEMS = 100; //change based on total # of unique items
    private Stock[] d_list; //creation of Stock array object
    private int d_nextItem; //used to count total # of unique items

    //constructor for inventory
    public Inventory(){
       d_list = new Stock[MAX_ITEMS];
       d_nextItem = 0;
    }

    //user imputs item and info and is inputed into stock array d_list
    //not used
    public void addStock(String name, String identifier, int quantity,
                        double unitCost, double sellingPrice ){

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      name = null;
      identifier = null;
      quantity = 0;
      unitCost = 0.0;
      sellingPrice = 0.0;
      String answer = null;
      String cont = null;

      while(!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no")){
         System.out.println("do you want to input an additional item into the stock manually?(yes or no)");
         answer = keyboard.next();
         if(!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no")){
            System.out.println("you must enter yes or no");
         }
      }
      if(answer.equals("yes")){
         while(cont.equals("yes")){ //having an error here
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the item");
            name = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the id tag");
            identifier = keyboard.next();
            System.out.println("Enter the quantity of "+name);
            quantity = keyboard.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter the Cost for the item");
            unitCost = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter the sales price of the item");
            sellingPrice = keyboard.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("do you want to enter info for a second item?");
            while(!cont.equals("yes") && !cont.equals("no")){
               cont = keyboard.next();
               System.out.println("you must enter yes or no");
            }
            d_list[d_nextItem] = new Stock(name, identifier, quantity, unitCost, sellingPrice);
            d_nextItem += 1;
         }
      }
      return;
    }

    public void loadInventory(String fileName)
    throws FileNotFoundException{
      if ( (fileName != null) && (!fileName.equals("")) ){
         Scanner ldInv = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
         String newLine = null;

         //initialization for variables
         String name = null;
         String identifier = null;
         int    quantity = 0;
         double unitCost = 0.0;
         double sellingPrice = 0.0;

         //reading of file into the Stock array
         while (ldInv.hasNextLine() && d_nextItem < MAX_ITEMS){
            if (ldInv.hasNextDouble()){
               System.err.println("Error:NO name of product detected!");
               System.exit(2);
            } else {
               name = ldInv.next();
            }
            if (ldInv.hasNextDouble()){
              System.err.println("Error:NO product identifier detected!");
              System.exit(2);
            } else {
               identifier = ldInv.next();
            }
            if (ldInv.hasNextInt()){
               quantity = ldInv.nextInt();
            } else {
               System.err.println("Error: Quantity of item is missing!");
               System.exit(2);
            }
            if (ldInv.hasNextDouble()){
               unitCost = ldInv.nextDouble();
            } else {
               System.err.println("Error: Price of Item is missing!");
               System.exit(2);
            }
             if (ldInv.hasNextDouble()){
               sellingPrice = ldInv.nextDouble();
            } else {
               System.err.println("Error: Sales price of Item is missing!");
               System.exit(2);
            }
            d_list[d_nextItem] = new Stock(name, identifier, quantity, unitCost, sellingPrice);
            newLine = ldInv.nextLine();
            d_nextItem += 1;
         }
      }
      if (d_nextItem == 0){
         System.err.println("There is no data in this file");
         System.exit(2);
      }
      return;
    }

    //prints onto screen data taken from file in a format to align with headings
    public void printInventory(){
      System.out.println();
      System.out.println(d_list[0]);
      for (int i = 0; i < d_nextItem; i++){
         Stock stock = d_list[i];
          System.out.format("%-20s\t%9s\t%1d\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\n",
stock.getName(),
                           stock.getIdentifier(), stock.getQuantity(), stock.getUnitCost(),
                           stock.getSellingPrice(), stock.getTotalCost(), stock.getTotalSellingPrice());
      /*
         System.out.println(stock.getName() + "\t" + stock.getIdentifier() + "\t" +
                            stock.getQuantity() + "\t" + stock.getUnitCost() + "\t" +
                            stock.getSellingPrice() + "\t" + stock.getTotalCost() +
                            "\t" + stock.getTotalSellingPrice());
      */

      }
      return;
    }
    //calculates total value of all items from the file
    public double getTotalSalesPrice(){
      double totalSP = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < d_nextItem; i++){
         Stock stock = d_list[i];
         totalSP += stock.getTotalSellingPrice();
      }

      return totalSP;
    }
    //calculates total cost of all items from the file
    public double getTotalCost(){
      double totalV = 0.0;
      for (int i = 0; i < d_nextItem; i++){
         Stock stock = d_list[i];
         totalV += stock.getTotalCost();
      }

      return totalV;
    }
    /*
     //user inputs name returns info from stock
    //not used
    public Stock getStock(String name){
    }
    */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
      String name = null;
      String identifier = null;
      int quantity = 0;
      double unitCost = 0.0;
      double sellingPrice = 0.0;
      if (args.length!=1){
             System.err.println("Usage:java Inventory <input file name>");
             System.exit(1);
          }
      Inventory inventory = new Inventory();
      inventory.addStock(name, identifier, quantity, unitCost, sellingPrice);
      inventory.loadInventory(args[0]);
      inventory.printInventory();
      System.out.format("\nTotal potential sales from inventory = %6.3f\n",
                        inventory.getTotalSalesPrice());
      System.out.format("\nTotal store cost of inventory = %6.3f\n",
                        inventory.getTotalCost());

     }
    }
```

stock.java

```
public class Stock{
private String d_name;
private String d_identifier;
private int    d_quantity;
private double d_unitCost;
private double d_sellingPrice;

public Stock(String name, String identifier, int quantity,
            double unitcost, double sellingprice){
  d_name = name;
  d_identifier = identifier;
  d_quantity = quantity;
  d_unitCost = unitcost;
  d_sellingPrice = sellingprice;
}
public String getName(){
  return d_name;
}
public String getIdentifier(){
  return d_identifier;
}
public int getQuantity(){
  return d_quantity;
}
public double getUnitCost(){
  return d_unitCost;
}
public double getSellingPrice(){
  return d_sellingPrice;
}
//sets the quantity of an item
public void setQuantity(int quantity){
  d_quantity = quantity;
}
//returns calculation of total cost of one type of item
public double getTotalCost(){
  return (d_quantity*d_unitCost);
}
//returns calculation of total sales value of one type of item
public double getTotalSellingPrice(){
  return (d_quantity*d_sellingPrice);
}
public String toString(){
 //this is the form the string must fit
 //System.out.format("%-20s\t%9s\t%1d\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\n"
 return "Product Name,           Identifier,     Quantity,   Unit Cost,      Selling Price,  Total Cost,     Total Selling Price";
}
public static void main(String[]args){
  Stock stock = new Stock("movie", "0a1b2c3d4", 5, 10, 20);

  System.out.println(stock);
  System.out.format("%-20s\t%9s\t%1d\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\t%9.2f\n", stock.getName(),
                    stock.getIdentifier(), stock.getQuantity(),
                    stock.getUnitCost(), stock.getSellingPrice(),
                    stock.getTotalCost(),stock.getTotalSellingPrice());
  return;
}
```

Comment: You're explicitly setting `String answer = null;`. Why would you expect it to be populated?

Comment: And as a side node, I don't understand why you are passing `name`, `identifier`, `quantity`, `unitCost` and `sellingPrice` as parameters of `addStock()` just to reset them all at the beginning of the function.

Answer (score 2):

You are setting `answer` to `null` and then invoking a call

```
answer.equals("yes")
```

which throws a null pointer exception because `answer` is null.

You should either set it to something non-null like an empty string or as others have noted, ask for the input before comparing, so that it's definitely non-null, or use the Yoda-style equals check

```
"yes".equals(answer)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are setting `answer` to `null` and then comparing that against some `String` values. That doesn't make sense. You probably want to read some input from, for example, `System.in` into the variable `answer`, before comparing it to anything.

Answer (score 1):

Lets start with a code block of yours.

```
String answer = null;
String cont = null;

while(!answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no")){
```

Line 1: You set answer to null

Line 3: You query answer to see if it is equal to something.

Now, a little note on java. `Null` is a type, just like `String`. `Null` however, is a subset of any other type. What this means is that when you ask

`answer.equals()`

you are really saying to java, `new String(answer).equals()`.
Since answer is actually of type `null`, java is interpretting your code as `new Null().equals()`

The problem is, the type `null` has no methods. So it throws a `NullPointerException` because you can never call methods on anything of `null` type.

Answer (score 0):

You are explicitly setting `String answer = null`, and then immediately attempting to invoke a method on it in your while loop (where you do `answer.equals...`).

Given the logic of this part of the program, you should be safe to use a `do...while` loop instead. Like so:

```
do{
    // get user input, set answer variable
while(answer.equals("yes") && !answer.equals("no"));
```

Answer (score 0):

dont declare `answer` as null whilst using the while loop, try reading an input first or initialise it with something invalid like `(" ")` which won't be recognised but has initialised the string `answer`